TEMPDB files not correct
On my SQL Server 2019 ENT server, when I run
select * from sys.master_files

I see that TEMPDB has 8 data files and there are 8 data files in the folder.
However when I run
select * from tempdb.sys.database_files

I only see 1 data file. Also, when I select the properties of TEMPDB, and look at the files, I see only 1 data file.
I can delete the 7 extra files so they are not locked or in use by SQL Server.
When I restart the SQL Server service, all 8 data files appear and the whole thing repeats.
There are no startup scripts or SPs that run when the service starts.
What is going on?

Why would just go and you delete them?! Don't mess with the database files if you don't know what are doing with them.

If you read the documentation on tempdb, it links to an entire article on the subject on why there are multiple files. I assume you aren't running on a single threaded CPU.

Considering the amount you've paid for enterprise, perhaps you would be best talking to your DBA about what you've been up to... They can likely educate on the whys. Deleting the files like that could be disastrous for your business.
